# aws cli s3 bucket download command error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After using aws configure to setup access I can list all the files in an s3 bucket with:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my_bucket_name
```

but when I run:

```
aws s3 cp s3://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/ . --recursive
```

or

```
aws s3 sync s3://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/ .
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects     operation: Access Denied
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked - ie without amazon domain:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket_name .
```